# Will a door rubbing on the carpet cause excessive wear?

Tags: insulation, carpentry, carpet, renovation

We recently had carpet installed in our master bedroom.

We love it!  My husband trimmed the door,  it opens & closes well for me.

The door is touching or rubbing the carpet when opening & closing.

My question is; will this cause excessive wear because the door is touching the carpet as it opens and closes?

This also keeps out a draft,  if cut more it may cause a draft.

Comment: A lot of door have snags from a rough edge, especially if they are cut. I would finish the bottom of the door smooth to keep it from snagging. sanding and acrylic paint would work well.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much of the pile is being rubbed it could wear off some of the pile. It will also cause more wear if it's a berber type of carpet or some other type of looped pile where the door could wear off the top fibers.
What it will cause, especially on pile carpets is a 90 or 180 degree arc in the carpet where it rubs. However if it's not a deep rub it should look better after vacuuming or shampoing.
Bottom line is try to minimize the amount of contact between the door and carpet by trimming the door so it just contacts the top of the pile and you should be fine.

Comment: It also depends on how often you open/close the door.  If it's a door that is rarely moved, then it will not matter much.  If it's opened/closed often, then you may want to consider trimming the bottom of the door a but more until it's not rubbing.  My rule of thumb is: If you can feel the resistance from the carpet as the door moves, there is too much contact.

Comment: @jwh20 - Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

More importantly than the rubbing is the ventilation. Many heating and air conditioning systems rely on the space between the door and floor for the return air. that's why there is usually a good space between them. If you have that type of system and you block that space, your system will not operate as designed and you won't get the heat or AC that you need for the room.